# In the southern US, what are the advantages of Saint Augustine grass?

Tags: grass

Are there any advantages of growing Saint Augustine grass in the southern United States for residential lawns?

Answer (score 1):

" It is a medium- to high-maintenance grass that forms a thick, carpetlike sod, crowding out most weeds and other grasses. *Wikipedia*"

The advantages:
 Thick sod
 Crowds out most weeds and other grasses

Disadvantage: 
 Maintenance